# Splitting the application into two different hosting providers

Tags: database, web-applications, web-services, networks, amazon-ec2

Due to cost I am currently thinking of using AWS for scalable hosting of the node.js backend of the application that would be nice to have monitoring,load balancing and all the goodies of the AWS architecture.

The database system (currently OrientDB,PostgreSQL and redis) would be nice to have lots of mem and SSD disks and I have found several places with pricing at 1/4.

Does anyone know of any metrics for comparing database lagging with a network request overhead or is that a non-issue in today's fast networks?